# If we know the eigenvalues of a matrix $A$, and the minimal polynom $m_t(a)$, how do we find the Jordan form of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

We have just learned the ***Jordan Form*** of a matrix, and I have to admit that I did not understand the algorithm.

> Given $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & 2 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $, find the ***Jordan Form*** $J(A)$ of the matrix.

So what I did so far:

> (I) Calculate the polynomial: $P_A(\lambda) = (\lambda - 1)^2(\lambda -2)^2$.
>
> (II) Calculate the minimum polynomial: $m_A(\lambda) = P_A(\lambda) =(\lambda - 1)^2(\lambda -2)^2 $

But I am stuck now, how do we exactly calculate the Jordan Form of $A$?

And an extra question that has been confusing me. In this case, does $A$ have $4$ eigenvalues or $2$ eigenvalues?

Comment: I think this might interest you : http://people.virginia.edu/~mah7cd/Math551/JordanForm.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the minimal polynomial has degree $4$ which is the same order of the matrix, you know that $A$'s [smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) is 
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & m_A(\lambda )\end{pmatrix}$.

Therefore the elementary divisors (I'm not sure this is the correct term in english) are $(\lambda -1)^2$ and $(\lambda -2)^2$.

Theory tells you that one jordan block is $\color{grey}{(\lambda -1)^2\to} \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and the other is $\color{grey}{(\lambda -2)^2\to} \begin{pmatrix} 2 &1\\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$.

Therefore a possible JNF for $A$ is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 2 &1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$.

Regarding the extra question, it seems to be asking about the [geometric multiplicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Eigenspace_and_spectrum). In this case it has two eingenvalues and not four.

Comment: We did not learn Smith's normal form...

Comment: @TheNotMe The problem seems constructed to use smith's normal. In any case the answer below should help you then.

Comment: @TheNotMe Let me know if you still need help with this.

Comment: Is this true whenever the minimal polynomial is the same as the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: @TheNotMe Is what true?